# Regex in vue js template

Tags: regex, vue.js, url, hyperlink

Hello I have this property: text, and it contains a url but as plain text. I want to convert the url so it will be clickable.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <button class="fas fa-angle-down jwsingle__player__text__toggle" @click="toggle" :class="{ 'jwsingle__player__text__toggle--active': isOpen }">
        </button>
        <div v-show="isOpen" class="jwsingle__player__text__description">
            {{ text }}
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>    
    export default {
        name: 'jwplayer-text-toggle',
        props: {
            text: {
                type: String,
            },
        },
        data() {
            return {
                isOpen: false,
            }
        },
        methods: {
            toggle() {
                this.isOpen = !this.isOpen;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You need an `<a :src="text">click me</a>` tag. You should probably consider renaming "text" to "url" if it's always a URL

Comment: @maxshuty You mean `<a :href="text">` :)

Comment: @tony19 doh, yes

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to create a link with the URL displayed as its text. You can do the following:

```html
<div v-show="isOpen" class="jwsingle__player__text__description">
  <a :href="text">{{ text }}</a>
</div>
```

The `:` in front of `:href` is important as it binds the prop value of `text` instead of the string `"text"`.